# Smarty Compiler: Syntax error unknown tag

Tags: php, smarty

I have a function named `menu` in `parent.tpl`:

```
{function menu level=0}
  <ul class="level{$level}">
  {foreach $data as $entry}
    {if is_array($entry)}
      <li>{$entry@key}</li>
      {menu data=$entry level=$level+1}
    {else}
      <li>{$entry}</li>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
  </ul>
{/function}
```

I want to use this `menu` function in `child.tpl`

```
{extends file='./base.tpl'}

{block name=head}
  <link href="/css/mypage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="/js/mypage.js"></script>
{/block}

{block name=body}
    {$menu = ['item1','item2','item3' => ['item3-1','item3-2','item3-3' =>
    ['item3-3-1','item3-3-2']],'item4']}
    {menu data=$menu}
{/block}
```

But smarty errors:

```
:  Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:/Users/yangchangshu/smarty/child.tpl"  on line 11 "{menu data=$menu}" unknown tag "menu" <-- 
  thrown in
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You say you've defined the function in `parent.tpl`, but your child template extends `base.tpl`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

By the nature of inheritance template Processing the parent template is processed last in the chain. So {menu} is undefined when the child Template is being compiled.
Work around:
put {function menu....} in a subtemplate and {include} it in 
{block name=body}